# Inconsistencies with DataTime diff function in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

While using the `diff` function in the `DateTime` class in PHP, I have been noticing some weird inconsistencies.
All the following intervals should be less than a month since they are exactly 1 second less than a month, however, the last two are not:

```php
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
$date_diff =  (new DateTime('2021-01-01 00:00:00'))->diff(new DateTime('2021-01-31 23:59:59'));
echo $date_diff->format('%y Year %m Month %d Day')."\n"; // 0 Year 0 Month 30 Day (expected)

$date_diff =  (new DateTime('2021-02-01 00:00:00'))->diff(new DateTime('2021-02-28 23:59:59'));
echo $date_diff->format('%y Year %m Month %d Day')."\n"; // 0 Year 0 Month 27 Day (expected)

$date_diff =  (new DateTime('2021-03-01 00:00:00'))->diff(new DateTime('2021-03-31 23:59:59'));
echo $date_diff->format('%y Year %m Month %d Day')."\n"; // 0 Year 1 Month 2 Day (???)

$date_diff =  (new DateTime('2021-10-01 00:00:00'))->diff(new DateTime('2021-10-31 23:59:59'));
echo $date_diff->format('%y Year %m Month %d Day')."\n"; // 0 Year 1 Month 0 Day (???)
```

Comment: @nice_dev - it's trivial to reproduce. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c0d49cdbd5eb26edf60aeef0e5ff98293de539d5

Comment: @billynoah I recently just added `date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');` since the Australia/Sydney timezone was set in my php.ini. When not using the Australia/Sydney timezone, it seems to work as expected.

Comment: yup - and here's the explanation: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52480

Comment: @billynoah Ahh, overlooked the timezone set.

Comment: Hmm well setting my timezone for everything to UTC is a less than ideal solution :(